# How to set a active link as default when page first time load

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I need some help to set a link  as active as default when the page load the first time.

```
<style type="text/css">
a{
color:black;
}
a:hover{
color:white;
}
a:active{
color:blue;
}
</style>


<div>
<!--I want this fisrt link to be set as active by default-->
<a href="#"/>
<!--I want this one as normal-->
<a href="#"/>
</div>
```

Comment: The `active` pseudo-class indicates that an element is currently active (which I think roughly translates to "is currently the subject of a click"). I'm not quite sure why you'd want to set that on page load - it's not like you're fooling anybody that the link is currently being clicked on.

Comment: The reason for this is because the page has several links (like tabs) to navigate through the page, when the page its first time loads the page one of the links its like (home), which it should be active to indicate that the user its on that page.

Comment: then use a class like `<a class="current">`, not pseudo-classes like `a:active`, and change your CSS from `a:active` to `a.current`.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your help, my concern if I do that its that if I do that, would it change class when another link is hovered or active?
Thanks again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can change your markup to this:

```
<div>
<!--I want this first link to be set as active by default-->
<a href="#" id="focusmeplease"/>
<!--I want this one as normal-->
<a href="#"/>
</div>
```

Then you can use this JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('focusmeplease').focus();
```

Attach that JavaScript to page load [however you like](http://www.google.com/search?q=execute+javascript+on+document+load&) (I like [this way](http://onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript/chapter4.html), unless you're using jQuery, in which case use [`$(document).ready()`](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready)).

Answer (score 1):

1. Mark the "a" tags with a class (like "focus").
2. Set all the active "a" tags in the class "focus" with your preferred look.

```
<style type="text/css">
a
{color:black;}
a:hover
{color:white;}
a.focus:link, a.focus:visited
{color:blue;}
</style>

<div>
<a href="#" class="focus">This link is active by default.</a>
<a href="#">This is a normal link.</a>
</div>
```

Final note: I have also corrected the "a" tag because was wrong.

Comment: This will not work. The first link will become blue only when it is being click. No default appearance. Down vote.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand well.

I have correct it, please verify if now it have the behavior that you want.

Comment: You can add or remove the following proprieties in order to change the behavior: link, visited and hover.

Answer (score 0):

```
a{
  color:black;
}
a:hover {
  color:white;
}
a:active, div a:first-child {
  color:blue;
}
```

Supported by most recent browsers, but not much more than that.

Comment: in which case the first-child a tag will always be blue, whether active or not.