# HTML set initial active menu option

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is similar to [How to set a active link as default when page first time load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147844/how-to-set-a-active-link-as-default-when-page-first-time-load) but I can't get it to work with this solution.

I have a menu in HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/gno1pzjv/

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#">option1</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">option2</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">option3</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">option4</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">option5</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">option6</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">option7</a> </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

When I select a menu option, the menu block should become yellow.

In my own code (but not in the fiddle) a menu option becomes yellow when selected, but the default page is not active at page startup. So currently the page always start with all options orange.

Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle, and shouldn't `$("#sub-header a")` be `$("#menu a")`? Seems to work if you fix that https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gno1pzjv/1/

Comment: That's right, "#sub-header a" should be "#menu a" and it does work in the fiddle, but why does it need  a link to fiddle.jshell.net to become active and what is the alternative for my page? Should my pages call the jQuery function at startup?

Comment: Make sure you're using `$(document).ready(...)` so that your javascript isn't executing too early. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Does the default page's list options href match the default page's url?

Answer (score 0):

In your JS:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#first").addClass("active");
        });
</script>
```

and in html:

```
<li id="first"> <a href="#">option1</a> </li>
```