# Independently scrolling divs break page-up/down

Tags: css

I'm hoping you can point me in the right direction.

I've got a webpage design consisting of two divs - a sidebar and main content area. Each one scrolls up/down independently using CSS alone. I've tested it in several key browsers and it displays well. On both touch enabled devices and with a mouse, it all scrolls as intended.

It's the page-up/down buttons that don't work when the page is initially loaded which might seem trivial, but I'm not happy with this. If the user clicks/taps the div they want to scroll, then the page-up/down buttons work.

I'm a bit bewildered about what direction to go in and need advice on where I'm best spending my time:

- seeking a 'fix' on my existing CSS
- creating a div:hover rule
- exploring Javascript to create a default 'focus' state for the #right-block?

I'm not sure it's a 'hover', a 'focus' issue, or something else, so some steer on this might be all I need.

Hope that's all clear. Thank you. Code below:

**HTML:**

`<div id="page-wrap">
   <div id="left-block"></div>
   <div id="right-block"></div>
</div>`

**CSS:**

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#page-wrap {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    will-change: overflow;
}
#left-block, #right-block {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
}
#left-block {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom:6em;
    width: 260px;
}
#right-block {
    width: calc(100% - 260px);
}
#left-block::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem because the code provided does not do anything. https://jsfiddle.net/7gqo4o1h/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest Adam. I've added some text so it exhibits the issue. Try your page-up/down keyboard buttons -> nothing happens. http://jsfiddle.net/f1d1prhc/3/

Comment: This post might serve helpful. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/2147869/3247527](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2147869/3247527)

Comment: @GirlCoder it is working for me

Comment: Intrigued you say it's working @AdamBuchananSmith as it's consistently not for me across hardware, OS and browsers. So when you load the page and immediately press the page-down keyboard button, the right-hand block only scrolls?

Comment: @TechTho. Thank you, that has sorted it. I did bet on it being a Javascript go-to I needed to pursue and found the code you've identified after posting my question. Of course browsers without js enabled... hum.

Comment: I considered using #left-block:focus and #right-block:focus to activate the column if the mouse pointer was over one or the other. A high likelihood since your columns are full screen.

Comment: Thank you again @TechTho. I'm going to experiment with doubling up using both of your suggestions or some sort of stylesheet for no-js so hopefully I've covered the bases on it. I'm well on the way with this now. 

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: welcome, happy coding!